# Remove a class from a <li> using Walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I want to remove a class from 2 lvl depth,from li tags of ul class="sub-ul".How can I do that using Walker?

```
<ul class="navigation d-block">
                                <li class="d-inline-block">
                                    <a href="#" class="active">About</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-ul">
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission & vision</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="d-inline-block">
                                    <a href="#">For patients</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="d-inline-block">
                                    <a href="#">Activities</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="d-inline-block">
                                    <a href="#">Project</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="d-inline-block">
                                    <a href="#">Event</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                           <?php
                                //Show the navigation menu
                                wp_nav_menu(array(
                                    'theme_location'    =>  'primary-nav',
                                    'menu_class'        =>  'navigation d-block',
                                    'walker'            =>  new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                                    ));
                            ?>
```

Comment: Where is the walker? How do you display the menu on your page (i.e. using `wp_nav_menu()`?

Comment: @SallyCJ sorry forgot to add the code.Edited and added the code

Comment: Ok, but where is the walker code? I.e. the `My_Walker_Nav_Menu` class. Or you don't have it?

Comment: @SallyCJ That's what I'm asking can I remove a class  from <li> dropdown menu tags  using Walker?With Walker I'm only replacing sub-menu to my custom class class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-ul\">\n";
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the Walker to remove classes from nav menu items. There is a filter, [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) which can be used to modify the classes on menu items.

> Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item’s list item element.

This, for example, would remove the classes from *all* menu items:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', '__return_empty_array' );
```

But you don't want that, you only want to remove classes for menus that are using a specific walker. One of the arguments passed to callbacks for this filter is `$args`, which contains the arguments used when the menu is output. This will include which Walker was used. So in the callback to the function you could check the Walker and remove all classes if it's yours:

```
function wpse_309490_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( is_a( $args->walker, 'My_Walker_Nav_Menu' ) ) {
        $classes = [];
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_309490_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

In your example markup though, it looks like your top-level items *do* have a class, and a custom one at that. In that case you can use the `$depth` argument to add a class for top-level items and no classes for other items:

```
function wpse_309490_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( is_a( $args->walker, 'My_Walker_Nav_Menu' ) ) {
        if ( $depth === 0 ) {
            $classes = ['d-inline-block'];
        } else {
            $classes = [];
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_309490_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: This way it's removing all other WP classes that are added automatically to the li tags and leaves only d-online-block.I want to add active class to current-menu-item but that doesn't exist after I use your code for walker.menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-32 current_page_item menu-item-106 all these classes are now removed and only d-inline-block is left.

Comment: If you want to keep the original classes change `$classes = ['d-inline-block'];` to `$classes[] = 'd-inline-block';`